# What is a synonym for inappropriately installed

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, synonyms

I'm trying to find an adjective that means something that was placed or installed incorrectly in a location such that it is causing problems and needs to be removed. Something like:

> Incompetent subcontractors had installed a speed bump on the highway.
>   The state transportation department removed the *blank* device.

Comment: You could use *botched*, although it's normally used with *job* as in *botched job*.

Comment: *Incongruous* covers some of the territory.

Comment: Traffic calming measures tend to be covered by regulation, therefore consider *noncompliant*. Otherwise consider, *obstructive* or *problematic*.

Comment: I like noncompliant best so far.

Comment: Bodged installation.

Comment: I would say "misfit".

Comment: In my thesaurical explorations I came across "pointless" - "having little or no sense, use, or purpose." That might work. Strictly speaking, the definition of pointless doesn't carry a negative connotation, but I believe in common usage it often does have one.

Answer (score 1):

How about ***misinstalled***?

If you google ***misinstalled***, you'll get numerous hits of various *misinstallations*. I didn't find it in any of the dictionaries I checked, but according to Google and other sources, *mis-* means wrongly, badly, or unsuitably. So ***misinstalled*** means *wrongly installed*, *badly installed*, or *unsuitably installed*, i.e., ***inappropriately installed***.

> Incompetent subcontractors had installed a speed bump on the highway.
>   The state transportation department removed the ***misinstalled*** device.

Comment: I like this idea. I feel like whatever the word is, it probably starts with a mis- or maybe a mal-

Answer (score 0):

I would say the best fit is [ineffective](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ineffective):

adjective

1.
not effective; not producing results; ineffectual:
ineffective efforts; ineffective remedies.

2.
inefficient or incompetent; incapable:
an ineffective manager.

Or [inadequate](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/inadequate?s=t):

adjective

1.
not adequate or sufficient; inept or unsuitable.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a better single adjective than "misplaced".  A speed bump doesn't belong on a highway, ergo one installed on a highway is by definition *misplaced*.  The first sentence ("Incompetent subcontractors ... ") makes this 100% clear, so no possible ambiguity can be occasioned by the use of "misplaced" in this case.  The entire paragraph needs to be considered here, not just the sentence where the adjective is sought.

Answer (score 0):

The *extraneous* device.

Extraneous means: not relevant or appropriate

http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/extraneous

Comment: I feel like extraneous doesn't have enough of a negative connotation. Extraneous stuff is not needed and perhaps wasteful, but doesn't actively cause problems.